# How to pass data between 2 or more ACTIVATED JFrames?

Tags: java, forms, swing, jframe

In C# this is done by using delegates and event, here is the link: [Passing Data between Windows Forms](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17371/Passing-Data-between-Windows-Forms).

My requirement is like this. User have to search the item code by loading the whole items from the database to a new form's `JTable`, this new form is shown by clicking a button in the main form (or any other form). After that appears, user Double click on specific item code in the table and that item code is passed to the main form's (or any other form's) text field and closed the current form.

here is the output from  c# https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_lPkc1YV2vQ&feature=youtu.be

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Comment: @AndrewThompson: to the OP's credit, this does appear to be a decent spot for a modal dialog.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels  ..You almost wrote that like modal dialogs were not mentioned in the linked Q&A.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: I have to admit that it's been a while since I've read/re-read that link. It is a great one though and wish I could up-vote it many times, but alas, I don't live in Chicago any more.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing values between JFrames](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017063/passing-values-between-jframes)

Answer (score 1):

The second window should not be a JFrame, but rather a JDialog, possibly modal. If it is modal, then the calling window will know when the 2nd dialog window closes, since program flow stops at the calling code immediately from when the dialog is displayed (think of how JOptionPanes work) and does not resume until the 2nd dialog window closes. It is right then that you would extract pertinent data from the objects associated with the dialog window, and this information can be obtained by simple means such as by calling appropriate getter methods.

e.g.,

```
JDialog someDialog = new JDialog(myJFrame, "My Dialog", ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
someDialog.add(myContentPaneWithMyGui);
someDialog.pack();
someDialog.setVisible(true);

// here code flow stops until the dialog is no longer visible.

// now call my getter to extract data
SomeType someData = myContentPaneWithMyGui.getSomeData();
```

Comment: i've done this in C# like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_lPkc1YV2vQ&feature=youtu.be .can u please tell me to do this in Java :)

Comment: @Macmarc25: I thought I just did.

Comment: what is myJFrame and myContentPaneWithMyGui?

Comment: @Macmarc25: placeholders for whatever is your JFrame and whatever JPanel you put into your JDialog.

Comment: Can u please show me how to write getter methods on this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick with your event/delegate way of doing, you could consider using [BeansBinding](https://java.net/projects/beansbinding).

It requires your model to fire events when their data changes, and add your Swing GUI elements registers as propertyListeners on those models.

Comment: To the original poster, Macmarc25, this is an excellent answer that supports an MVC (model-view-control) design. 1+

Comment: Yeah, but kind of overkill for what you wanna do... The JDialog is a way better/simpler answer.