# When using JPanels in java how can you display user input data in one class to another

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I've been having some difficulty with this. Basically I want a user to enter a name in one Java class and have that data displayed in another. I try using gets but I keep getting 'null'. Also how would you do this if I wanted to get an int from my class (exampl) to display in my second class. Would it basically be the same?

Here's an example to show what I mean

1st class

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Exampl extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JLabel intro = new JLabel("Welcome What is your name?");
    JTextField answer = new JTextField(10);
    JButton button = new JButton("Enter");
    final int WIDTH = 330;
    final int HEIGHT = 330;
    JLabel greeting = new JLabel("");
    JButton next =new JButton("Next");
     String name = answer.getText();

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public Exampl() {
        super("Welcome");
        setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(intro);
        add(answer);
        add(button);
        add(greeting);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        Object source = event.getSource();
        if (source == button) {
             String greet = "Hello there" + name;
             greeting.setText(greet);
              add(next);
       next.addActionListener(this);

           if(source==next)
            dispose();
            new Hello();
        }

    }


      public static void main(String[] args) {
        Exampl frame= new Exampl();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

2nd class

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Hello extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    String name;
    JLabel hi = new JLabel("Nice to see you "+name);
    JButton button = new JButton("Enter");
    final int WIDTH = 330;
    final int HEIGHT = 330;
    JLabel greeting = new JLabel("");
    JButton next =new JButton("Next");

    public Hello() {
        super("Welcome");
        setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(hi);
        add(button);
        add(greeting);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        Object source = event.getSource();
        if (source == button) {
             String greet = "example " + name;
             greeting.setText(greet);
              add(next);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Exampl frame= new Exampl();
        frame.setVisible(true);           
    }        
}
```

Comment: Yeah. I just added the second class to show what I mean. I want whatever value is inputted to go to the next JPanel. For example if someone writes down 'Fred' in the first class I want that value to be able to be displayed on the second class

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing values between JFrames](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017063/passing-values-between-jframes)

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful in that it simplifies things but I want to know how to move a value to another class (such as int). I'm planning on doing a project where I add the inputted name and a random int into a file so I can store it. Or would it make more sense to add that code into the same class?

Comment: Read the edit on my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recommendations for you:

1. Don't extend `JFrame`, instead extend `JPanel`. See: [Extends `Frame` vs creating it inside the program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22003802/extends-jframe-vs-creating-it-inside-the-the-program) and [Why shouldn't you extend `JFrame` and other components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143923/why-shouldnt-you-extend-jframe-and-other-components)
2. Don't use multiple `JFrames`. See [The use of multiple `JFrames`, good / bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-or-bad-practice) (**BAD**) instead you might want to try using [Card Layout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html#card) or [`JDialog`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)s

> What do you mean by extend? do you mean "public class Hello extends Exampl"? I'm new to java so I don't know much.

3. From that comment on another answer, you might want to learn the basics first in console applications before going into a GUI application which adds more complexity to your programs and thus your learning.

> I'm planning on doing a project where I add the inputted name and a random int into a file so I can store it. Or would it make more sense to add that code into the same class?

4. From that comment, you can create a public method which returns the value in a `JTextField` in the format you need, then call that method from the other class, for example:

   ```
   public String getUserName() {
       return userNameField.getText();
   }

   public int getDigit() {
       try {
           return Integer.parseInt(digitField.getText());
       } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
           nfe.printStackTrace();
       }
       return -1; //In case it's not a number, or return 0, or whatever you need
   }

   //------In another class------//

   int digit = object1.getDigit(); //Where object1 is an instance of the other class where those methods are defined
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You've been very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Make a getter in first class and extends second one class then use super.getter();

Comment: What do you mean by extend? do you mean "public class Hello extends Exampl"? I'm new to java so I don't know much.